# How do I test my viewstate which is a stateflow made using combining multiple flows

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-flow

My ViewModel

```
    val username = MutableStateFlow("")
    val password = MutableStateFlow("")

   val state = combineFlows(
        username,
        password,
    ) { username, password->
        LoginViewState(
            username = username,
            password = password,
        )
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, WhileSubcribed(5000), initial = LoginViewState.Initial)
```

I can test that if the username variable updates or not using turbine like this:

```
    @Test
    fun testIfCredentialsUpdate() = runTest {
        viewModel.onUsernameChange("usr")
        viewModel.username.test {
            assertThat(awaitItem()).isEqualTo("usr")
            cancel()
        }
    }
```

but I'm unable to test that after my username variable updates, does my state updates or not. The test fails and my viewstate is always at the initial/default stage.
If there is more better way to test viewstates which has combine, please let me know :)